# access dropbox datastore in .NET

Tags: .net, dropbox

Ive written an android app that uses the dropbox datastore. Id now like to access that data from a .NET application but I cant figure out how. I couldnt find a .net api specific to the datastore. Could I possibly access it another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, there's really no good solution for this. There's no .NET SDK, and the HTTP API isn't (yet) documented, so you can't really build your own.